# How do I determine the length of a constant string?

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler, att

I have defined a string label as follows in the data section:

```
.data
    array:
        .string "Hello World!"
```

My question is, how would I go about retrieving the length of the string (11)? Do I have to use a for loop and iterate through every bit in the memory section occupied by the string label until I find a character (integer section of 4 bytes) set to 0?

Comment: Yes, if it's not a constant string. Otherwise you could of course have the assembler count the length for you. PS: Note that the terminator, like all the other characters in a `.string`, is a single byte, not 4.

Comment: @Jester The string array is constant and will not change throughout the execution of the program. Thus, how would I have the assembler count the length for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the address of the byte following the string, and subtract the address of `array`.

This can be done by placing another label at the end of the string, or by using `.` which refers to the current address.  Examples:

```
    .data
str1:
    .string "Hello"
str1_end:
    str1_len = (str1_end - str1)

str2:
    .string "Goodbye"
    str2_len = (. - str2)

    .text
    .global foo
foo:
    movl $str1_len, %eax
    movl $str2_len, %ebx
```

This assembles into

```
    movl $6, %eax
    movl $8, %ebx
```

By the way, if your string is really constant, consider placing it in `.section .rodata` instead of `.data`.